# OBR server implementation

Tags: java, osgi, obr

I'm playing with OSGi. For what I understand, in order to install and start a bundle you need to already have resolved its dependencies. Since manually installing its direct (and indrect) dependencies can be painful, OBR has been introduced.

I'm using Felix as OSGi framework implementation  and I would like to automatically resolve dependencys of my bundles via OBR (i.e. guava library). For this very reason I'm using `org.apache.felix.bundlerepository` on the client.

I'm unsure about what to do on the server side. I couldn't find solid information about what to do. I'm sure Felix can be easily configured on the server in order to serve as "OBR server" but I do not know how to do it. 
Can you please me help me? Code would be highly appreciated. If you can't post code, could at least tell me the general steps (or link a resource) I need in order to successfully setup the repository (like bundles required on the felix framework or another software implementing such feature).

My setup right now:

- Felix;
- Eclipse Neon;
- Maven for eclipse (1.7);

Thanks for all the reply!

Comment: What do you mean by "on the server side"? Do you want to know how to deploy bundles to an OSGi instance or how to setup a repository where bundles can be fetched from when resolving dependencies like from a maven repository?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I want to setup a repository where I can fetch bundles from an OSGi instance to resolve dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

There is an OBR plugin for [Sonartype Nexus 2.13](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/osgi-sect-intro.html%20Sonartype%20Nexus%202.13), which allows you to provide an OBR-compatible repository. It can also be used to proxy an existing Maven repository.

However, before setting up your own repository, you might also want to have a look at [bndtools](http://bndtools.org/) and their approach to resolving dependencies. Bndtools also allows you to rely on existing Maven repositories that do not support OBR explicitly. There is a [guide on how to work with Maven](http://enroute.osgi.org/tutorial_maven/050-start.html), which explains their approach.

Comment: I''m already using BND tools (in particular maven-bundle-plugin) to update my OBR repo within my local maven repository with my under development bundles. But what about third party bundles (like com.google.guava just for example)? I would be silly to download the source codes (if available), create a maven project and use maven-bundle-plugin to update the OBR repository.xml file. Maybe (and probably) I'm missing something. Is there no way to say "please add the following bundle x.jar inside my OBR repository". Again, sorry if my question was unclear

Answer (score 1):

The "server side" of an OBR repository simply consists of an index file which in turn contains URL links to the bundles. You can provide this without any special server software. An Apache or Nginx HTTP server would suffice, for example.

Comment: I'm aware the OBR consist only in a single XML file and I'm aware there are tools (like BNDTools or maven-bundle-plugin) which, given a project under development, can generate you the correct xml file. But suppose you need to add other dependencies (like ´guava´ library): it would be silly to manually create such xml. Is there a tool that can help you adding the data for you automatically? Something like: "i want to add to my OBR repo ´com.google.guava:19.0´ do ´obr-add /home/koldar/com.google.guava.jar´.

Comment: The tool to generate an index is called bindex. There are numerous ways to use it. Most simply you can run it as a command-line tool whenever your repo content changes. Alternatively there are ways of getting the file to automatically generate the index whenever the repo changes, but this requires some additional server-side logic. Perhaps you could say what way you would *like* it to work and I will tell you whether and how that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

[Karaf Cave](https://karaf.apache.org/projects.html#cave) provides an OSGI Bundle Repository.

Comment: can it run on felix? I know framework implementations may define configurations specific for themselves (i.e. felix.auto.deploy.dir)

Comment: It is a collection of bundle, so it can certainly run on felix, but you should consider use it in Karaf container, would be easier to configure, manage and run.